# In Flask, how do I print the python list to Jinja template?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, flask, jinja2

I have a few lists that I use to calculate Cartesian Product:

python.py:

```
@app.route('/output', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def output():
    a = ['one','two']
    b = ['three','four']
    c = ['five']
    d = ['six','seven','eight'] 
    e = ['nine','ten','eleven']

   cpl = list(itertools.product(a,b,c,d,e))
   return render_template('output.html',cpl = cpl)
```

output.html:

```
{% for cp in cpl %}
  <p>{{ cp }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I am being returned a blank screen.

When I am running the same python code in Jupyter, I get the lists returned.

Where might I have a problem?

Comment: It may just be an issue with your current setup. I ran your code locally, and I got the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

cpl returns a list of tuples, it's not a single value. Maybe that's confusing Jinja. You could either make a nested for loop or try casting those tuples to strings before rendering the template.

For example, try adding

```
strings = [str(c) for c in cpl]
return render_template("output.html", cpl=strings)
```

Comment: Doubt so. The setup works fine for me, producing tuple string representations.

Comment: I tried converting, it didn't help. Where would I create a nested loop - in python or jinja?

Comment: If the setup works fine for @alecxe and converting didn't help, then I'd double check everything else.

Comment: @minterm when I try to pass one of the lists separately, for example list "a"(changing parameter in render_template to 'a=a'), it does show the content in jinja, but not the cpl

Comment: @FeyziBagirov try rendering it with the string conversion I just added. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @minterm didn't work unfortunately. I tried jsonify it, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked is:

python.py

```
@app.route('/output', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def output():
    a = ['one','two']
    b = ['three','four']
    c = ['five']
    d = ['six','seven','eight'] 
    e = ['nine','ten','eleven']
    newArray = []
    newArray = [a, b, c, d, e]
    cpl = list(itertools.product(*[i for i in newArray if i != []]))
    return render_template('output.html',cpl = cpl)
```

output.html:

```
{% for cp in cpl %}
<p> {{ cp }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```